# Python logic error in 'if' evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04

I've just had the strangest error. I haven't had a chance to fully debug it, but I wanted to post this and see if anyone else has had a similar issue.

### Problem

The following code is in a function that downloads a file. The `if` statement logic is intended to skip the download step if the final file exists.

```
log.debug('force: {}, isfile: {}'.format(force, os.path.isfile(fasta_path)))
log.debug('if result: {}'.format(force or not os.path.isfile(fasta_path)))

if force or not os.path.isfile(fasta_path):
    # we don't have the file, so download it
    log.info('Downloading reference FASTA')
else:
    log.info('FASTA found--skipping download.')
```

When run, the following prints out:

```
[17-02-14 05:03:32 - __main__:119 - DEBUG] force: False, isfile: True
[17-02-14 05:03:32 - __main__:120 - DEBUG] if result: False
[17-02-14 05:03:32 - __main__:124 - INFO] Downloading reference FASTA
```

### Breakdown

The `force` variable is intended to allow the user to "force" the download to happen, regardless of existing data. As you can see in the output, it is `False`.

The path to the file is valid and the file exists, as seen in the output.

Thus, the if statement is essentially `False or not True`, which should (and does, also in the output) evaluate to `False`; however, the `True` conditional (`Downloading reference`) is executed.

I have tried parentheses and some minimal debugging, but I cannot find any reason for this to happen. For example, the following works as expected in the python interpreter:

```
if False or not True:
    print('hi')
else:
    print('bye')
```

### Environment

This issue occurs with Python 3.5 on ubuntu 16.04 within a docker container.

Comment: I feel like you've put a reasonable amount of work into this post, but still have avoided giving us an MCVE to work with...

Comment: Is `force` actually the string `"False"`?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the lines of code and re-writing them?  I'm not kidding, sometimes that works.

Comment: @turbulencetoo I'm not sure what more I could give...do you want the `os.path` import statement and the `force = False` command?

Comment: @muppetjones What is the datatype of `force`? You can find this out by printing the type:  `print(type(force))`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes. I tried completely rewriting the logic to `not force and os.path.isfile(fasta_path)`. Same results

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, `force` is `False` and the file does exist--as shown in the output.

Comment: I'm wondering if the os.path.isFile has a side effect? or if some short-circuiting is going on?

Comment: @muppetjones: The fact that you said both "yes" and "`force` is `False`" suggests that you're not clear on the difference between `False` and `"False"`. `False` is a boolean; `"False"` is a string, representing a sequence of 5 characters, which is considered True if treated as a boolean.

Comment: Try `print(type(force))` and `print(repr(force))`.

Comment: @leaf It's a boolean. It's set via `argparse` using the `default=False` (ish) argument. In actuality, it has the option to be set via an environment variable. This shouldn't be an issue as the statement still evaluates to false (see the second log statement).

Comment: @rajah9 That's exactly what I'm thinking, too

Comment: @muppetjones: Are you *sure* it's a boolean? Did you actually check? I can think of several ways it could end up as a string even with `default=False`.

Comment: I'm with the guys saying No MCVE. I agree it's puzzling, but that just means you haven't provided enough info. More code, please. If it makes you happier, create a standalone program that opens logger, collects args, and demonstrates that you're *not,* in fact, going nuts.

Comment: @muppetjones Do this: type `print(type(force))` in your program before your if statement. Of the output is `<class 'str'>` then `force` is a string. If the output is `<class 'bool'>` than your right, `force` is a variable. Which one is it?

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, I misread your comment as I was rushing out the door to a meeting--no, force is not a string, yes it is the value false.

Comment: add a line with `force = False` in front of the `if` line just to see what will happen, or put there something like `log.debug(force == False)`

Answer (score 4):

As noted by @user2357112 in the comments it seems very likely that `force` is a string:

```
>>> print('if result: {}'.format("False" or not True))
if result: False
>>> "False" or not True
'False'
>>> type("False" or not True)
<class 'str'>
>>> bool("False" or not True)
True
```

That's probably why the second debug statement shows False (because it shows the string and not the boolean). You can test this by either

```
log.debug('if result: {}'.format(bool(force or not os.path.isfile(fasta_path))))
```

(expected output `if result: True`) or

```
log.debug('if result: {}'.format(repr(force or not os.path.isfile(fasta_path))))
```

(expected output `if result: 'False'` - note the quotes signalling it's a string and not a boolean)

**Edit** Explanation: According to [4.2. Boolean Operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) the expression `x or y` is evaluated according to `if x is false, then y, else x`. Since according to [4.1. Truth Value Testinge](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) only empty sequences are `False` (in the context of truth value testing) the sequence `'False'` is `True`. Thus `'False' or x` evaluates to the string `'False'` (independent of the value of `x`). During printing `'False'` is not interpreted as a boolean value. However in the if-statement the string `'False'` is  tested for `Truth` ...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, a slight modification of the code, running on a Windows machine, Python 2.6.5:

```
def stackOverflow(self, force, fasta_path):
    logging.info('force: {0}, isfile: {1}'.format(force, os.path.isfile(fasta_path)))
    logging.info('if result: {0}'.format(force or not os.path.isfile(fasta_path)))

if force or not os.path.isfile(fasta_path):
    # we don't have the file, so download it
    logging.info('Downloading reference FASTA')
else:
    logging.info('FASTA found--skipping download.')
```

This takes the expected path ("skipping download") of `force` is `False` and the path exists. The call is:

```
stackOverflow(False, r'C:\temp\pythoncode.txt')
```

Making the first argument a string, as the comments imply, will take the mystery path ("Downloading").

```
stackOverflow("False", r'C:\temp\pythoncode.txt')
```